# How to fetch text before an HTML tag using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I need to get details from an email that is sent to me. I need to place each value inside a variable and save it to database or save them on a hash first before saving to the database.

I'm using the Mail gem to retrieve the email using POP3, and Nokogiri for parsing the email. The data I need to retrieve is inside the `<span>` tag. However I also need to get the text before the `<span>` tag which will serve as the key for the text inside the tag. For instance, `Name: <span> My Name </span>`.

Expected output should be like this if saved in hash:

```
hash = ['Tour Name:' : 'Day Tour', 'Tour Date:' : '2019-06-07']
```

or at least I'm able to get the key and the values together.

Here is my code:

```
require 'net/imap'
require 'nokogiri'

class SomeClass

    def self.get_email
        Mail.defaults do
          retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "pop.gmail.com",
                                  :port       => 995,
                                  :user_name  => username,
                                  :password   => password,
                                  :enable_ssl => true
        end

        email = Mail.first.html_part.to_s
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(email)
        puts doc.css('span').map(&:text) <- gets text of span only
    end
end
```

Raw HTML code of the email:

```
 <tr>
  <td>
  Tour Name: <span style="font-weight:bold">Day Tour</span>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  Tour Date: <span style="font-weight:bold">June 07, 2019</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the raw HTML code of the email. If it is as simple as you showed, then the following code should work:

```
docs.css('td').map{|td| td.children.map(&:text)}
```

Then, you can convert it into a hash by calling `to_h`.

Of course, please remember that your elements might contain additional whitespaces that should be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @MrShemek is suitable for your HTML. If you have more hierarchy of nodes inside your inner children you can do:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(email).css('td').map{|t| r=t.css('span').remove; [t.text, r.text].map(&:strip)}.to_h
=> {"Tour Name:"=>"Day Tour", "Tour Date:"=>"June 07, 2019"}
```

The inner element is moved and remaining text is fetched, then forms a tuple with the text and inner text.